# Function in cartesian coordinate using winapi

Tags: c++, winapi

How can I draw simple function as for example |x| or x^2 with cartesian coordinate system in win32api? Is it possible?

Comment: Of course it's possible, but surely you can find some tutorial or book on win32api graphics?

Comment: What do you know how to do already? Do you know how to draw a line? If you can't do that, then concentrate on being able to do that first. Once you can do that, draw lots of them to make a curve.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible.  You probably want to use functions like [`MoveToEx()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145069%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`LineTo()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145029%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to draw line segments onto a GDI surface in your `WM_PAINT` handler.  Of course, you have to compute all of the data points yourself and pass them to Windows; it doesn't have any built-in functionality for graphing functions.

Comment: Ok, but how can I make cartesian coordinate system ? Also by using function MoveToEx() and LineTo() ?